# Understanding DI in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

I have two traits:

```
trait A {
  def a
}
```

And:

```
trait B { this: A =>
  def b
}
```

Now, I tried to use `trait B` as this:

```
def method(bTrait: B) = bTrait.a //error
```

but it refuses to compile. I thought we could rely on that any implementations of `B` always extends `A`. What's wrong? Why doesn't it compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought we could rely on that any implementations of `B` always
>   extends `A`

That's not what `this: A =>` means. What it means is: *"in order to use `B`, I require an instance of `A` to be provided at compile time"*. This can be done through [mixin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/mixin-class-composition.html)

Once you understand that, you can do:

```
def method(bTrait: B with A) = bTrait.a
```

Comment: What do you mean be provided at compile time? If I don't make a class implementing both of traits I get the error _llegal inheritance, self-type BImpl does not conform to A_. so it means it should implement both of traits.

Comment: @user3663882 It means that in order to work with an instance of `B`, you need to mixin something of type `A` into it.

Comment: Ah...,  got it. Thank you.